# My bash code won't print the value of count for the else statement. The output is just "Sorry, the correct answer is ."

Tags: printing

```
read usr_option

op1=$(((RANDOM % 500) +1))
op2=$(((RANDOM % 500) +1))

# Your script should start here
if [ "$usr_option" == "1" ]
        then count=$((op1 + op2)) echo "$op1 + $op2 = "
                read usr_answer
                if  [ "$usr_answer" == "$count" ]
                        then echo "Congratulations! That is right."
                else
                        echo "Sorry, the correct answer is $count."
                fi
```

I tried putting $count in quotation marks, moving it outside the output quotation marks with quotation marks of its own.